# Change GNOME terminal colours when running screen

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-screen, tmux

I'm using GNOME Terminal on CentOS 5.

I have the terminal settings customized to use the colours I like. However when I run screen (or tmux) the colours for my terminal input lines are always inverted.

**Is there a way to turn off the inverting?**

**EDIT:** My TERM is set to "xterm".

Comment: What is the value of `TERM` before and after you start `tmux` or `screen`?

Comment: @chepner: inside tmux: screen-256color,  outside tmux: xterm,  inside screen: screen

Comment: Have you tried `TERM=xterm-256color tmux` to start tmux?

Answer (score 0):

May this help you? Send escaped reset command to the term:

```
echo $'\e[0m'
```

Or, send command to change the fg/bg color, according to the color table:

[image: color table]

in the format of `<ESCAPE>[<X>;<Y>m`. For example, change to blue backcolor and yellow forecolor:

```
echo $'\e[44;33m'
```

Which should look like:

[image: 2]

Comment: Doesn't seem to help.    No matter what colours I tried to choose there is something else overriding it, and I still have no control over the look of the characters.